# Exact differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was finding the solution of a differential equation. But I'm stuck on this part. I tried simple integration but answer is incorrect. I don't know how to solve this.

$$
dz=(6x+3y)dx+(3x-4y)dy
$$

Comment: you probably mean $(6x+3y)dx+(3x-4y)dy=0$ ? or what is the $dz$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT

$dz = (6x+3y)dx+(3x-4y)dy=0,\quad \frac{\partial (6x+3y)}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial (3x-4y)}{\partial x}$

$\Rightarrow \,dz\,$ is the total differential of function $z = f(x,y),$

I would say, find the function $z = f(x,y)$:

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= 6x+3y \Rightarrow \, z = \int (6x+3y)\,dx=3x^2+3xy+\phi(y)$

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}= 3x-4y \Rightarrow \, z = \int (3x-4y)\,dy=3xy-2y^2+\psi(x)$

$\Rightarrow \,z=3x^2+3xy-2y^2+C$